# How do I sum up over an uncontrolled set?

Tags: optimization, set, gams-math

I have to develelop a mcp model using GAMS. I am not quite experienced with this program but the error compilation website was not quite helpful either.

I have tried varying the indices but this would only change the error from uncontrolled set to controlled set. I did also try using the Alias function but either I did it wrong or it did not work at all.

```
Variables
 lambda(p)       shadow price
;

POSITIVE VARIABLES
         R(t,p)    production
         S(t,p)    Stock at time t
;
```

```
RES_resource_lambda(p)..
         -(SUM(t, R(t,p)) - S(t,p)) =g= 0
;
```

Comment: It might help if you post the exact error(s) you're receiving. (edit the post, do not post them as a comment)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is about the last t in the equation:

```
RES_resource_lambda(p)..
         -(SUM(t, R(t,p)) - S(t,p)) =g= 0
;
```

The `t` in `R(t,p)` is controlled by the `SUM`, but nothing controls the `t` in `S(t,p)`. You need to specify, what you want to do with this one, e.g. add it to the `SUM` as well.